# image colors change when starting application with launch file

Tags: kinect, roslaunch, qt, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone,

we are writing a user cockpit application which should serve as a way to control our robot, this cockpit shows 3 camera images, one from the kinect, 2 from two webcams.

when we start the cockpit application with a launch file on a machine connected to the robot, the cockpit shows all 3 of the images but the red and the blue channels of the images from the kinect are swapped.(everything that red shows up blue and the other way around).
whenever we start the cockpit manually the same thing happens, except that both the webcams swap the blue and red channel, and the kinects colors are normal.

we have tried starting removing all other applications and parameters from the launch file, this gives the same result

the cockpit application is written in QT4.7.0 and both machines run diamondback on ubuntu 10.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10209/image-colors-change-when-starting-application-with-launch-file/) by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2011-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using OpenCV, the image format is BGR, not RGB. So if you are using OpenCV images and not converting them properly, that might be the answer.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are (at least) two differences when running with roslaunch vs. rosrun/manually.

- Extra parameters like __log are passed
- You are in a different working directory

I would suggest finding out why the channels are swapped at all, as that seems to be some memory bug that is probably just triggered in another way.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1